# Javascript ( jQuery ) Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have a simple javascript/jquery function:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) {
   var widget_id_base = '099_cf_samurai_widget';

   if(settings.data.search('action=save-widget') != -1 &&
        settings.data.search('id_base=' + widget_id_base) != -1) {
         my_function_chosen_o99();
   }
}); 

function my_function_chosen_o99(){
   jQuery(".chzn-select").chosen();
}
```

Which works correctly, but when I add the width parameter:

```
function my_function_chosen_o99(){
   jQuery(".chzn-select").chosen(width:'95%');
}
```

It gives me an error:

```
Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
Source File: http://localhost/my-path/js/o99.chosen.init.js?ver=k99
Line: 20, Column: 41
Source Code:
      jQuery(".chzn-select").chosen(width:"95%"); 
.............................................|
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: It is related to a javascript syntax error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass an object as the argument(within `{}`)

```
 jQuery(".chzn-select").chosen({width:'95%'});
```

Comment: Thank you dear sir ... But why ?? I just followed the official documentation found here : http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html . is the documentation wrong ? I mean the problem is resolved , but I would really want to learn the reason :-)

Comment: @ObmerkKronen looks like there is a typo in that documentation

Comment: oh .. ok . Thanks. so for future reference - I ALWAYS need to pass options in that manner `{}` ??

Comment: @ObmerkKronen it depends on the function... but if it is an settings object then yes